# HTML will not connect to PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new working on a project that has me connecting a database and a webpage and before doing the official database, I wanted to test a basic database.

I test to make sure everything is working by using phpMyAdmin. I can tell that I formed SOME kind of connection between my html and php, but that's where the issue is. whenever I press the submit button on my site, instead of getting a message telling me that everything works, I instead get a white page with all of my php code. I have tried making sure all my syntax is correct and all the variables are labeled correctly, but nothing is going through.

```
<!DOCTYPE php>
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'training');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '********');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!link){
    die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error);
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!db_selected){
    die('Error: ' .mysql_error());
}
$Name = $_POST=['name'];
$Job = $_POST['job'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO employee (name,job) VALUES ('$Name', '$Job')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' .mysql_error());
}
echo 'Success!';
mysql_close();
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<h1 style="text-align:center">Undergrad Sign-up</h1>
<style>
#body {background-color:#001b38;}
</style>
<body id="body" style="color:white;text-align:center" >

<form action="DBconnect.php" method="post" />
Name<br>
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength=20 required/>
<br>
Job<br>
<input type="text" name="job" maxlength=20 required/>
<br>
<button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is one syntax error in your code `$Name = $_POST=['name'];` make it to `$Name = $_POST['name'];`

Comment: which server you use? zend,  wamp, xampp, ampp, or you use apache & php & mysql & manual config

Comment: There are more errors in the syntax `if(!link){`should be `if(!$link){` then change this line `die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error);`to `die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());` same with `if (!db_selected){`should be `if (!$db_selected){`

Comment: what is <!DOCTYPE php>

Comment: Ah, i'm blind. missing small things.

Comment: For simplicity in terms of php+mysql you could use [Database Abstraction Layer for MySQL using PHP](http://docs.dalmp.com/en/latest/Quickstart.html)

Comment: PHP already knows what is going wrong with your code and will be logging the details somewhere unless you told it not to.